# Compare Password from Database for Password Update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

This is how I create a user to seed my database

```
if (!context.Users.Any())
{
    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
    userManager.Create(user, "P@ssw0rd");
    context.AspNetUsersExtendedDetails.AddOrUpdate(userExtended);
    context.SaveChanges();

}
```

The issue happens when I try to update my password like this:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbContext);
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

var currentPasswordHash = userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(Input.CurrentPassword);
if(user.PasswordHash == currentPasswordHash)
{
    var passwordHash = userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(Input.NewPassword);
    user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    logger.Info(AspNetEventLogs.Update + " Password updated for User: " + user.UserName);
}
else
{
    logger.Error(AspNetEventLogs.Error + " Current password incorrect");
}
```

I cannot get the hashes to match at all. The method that I used to create the user and hash the password is similar. Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: While your question is interesting, please consider quickly using a salt to store your passwords

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What is the ComparePassword method?

Comment: Ow, I thought that was some user made methods, I'm used to using other external library like bouncy castle. thanks for the info.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for your help. I went with the VerifyHashedPassword method.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ooops, knee jerk reaction.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Noted. Will updated my code to do that also.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto so, shouldn't you turn your comments into an answer ? As I understood, OP's problem was solved thanks to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for [PasswordHasher.HashPassword](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Crypto.cs#L26) you will see this:

```
using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, PBKDF2IterCount))
{
    salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
    subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
}
```

So, a new salt and subkey is generated when you call it. That's why your check would never (as far as what has been proven, that is) return `true`.

For this specific purpose, `PasswordHasher` has a `VerifyHashedPassword` method that can recreate the hash using the stored salt and subkey -- this is what is called when you log in with Identity.

Notice, however, that your method [lacks the update of the user's SecurityStamp](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs#L608) which has to be updated when the password changes for security purposes.

Further, notice that all of that manual work you are doing was already thought of in the core libraries of Identity and all you have to do is call `UserManager.UpdatePasswordAsync` which will check the password before using the new one provided.